# Linq. Как Написать Select чтобы он брал все элементы массива

Tags: c#, linq

Есть

```
d = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                .Select(str => str.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }))
                .Select(str => str[0])
                .Select(str => Convert.ToDouble(str.Replace('.', ',')))
                .ToArray();
```

Что написать вместо `.Select(str => str[0])`, чтобы я обработал все элементы массива?

Comment: Убрать `.Select(str => str[0])` и в строке выше использовать `SelectMany`

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble(str.Replace('.', ','))` выглядит нехорошо, если запустите приложение на ПК с другой локалью - оно упадет. Надо использовать `IFormatProvider cInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US"); double.Parse(str, cInfo);`

Comment: @Nikita оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Андрей, invariant culture куда лучше, чем en-US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать метод расширения [`SelectMany`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany--2?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) вместо [`Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select--2?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__):

```
d = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                .SelectMany(str => str.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }))
                .Select(str => Convert.ToDouble(str.Replace('.', ',')))
                .ToArray();
```

[Подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany) об отличиях между `Select` и `SelectMany`.

Comment: А как теперь игнорировать те значения, которые не конвертируются в double?

Comment: Используйте `double.TryParse(...)` вместо `Convert.ToDouble(...)`.